# Is there a way to set up AVPlayer without specifying filetypes?

Tags: swift, avplayer, file-type

I am using a TableViewController to list content of multiple filetypes, say ".mov" and ".wav".
I want to open these files in AVPlayer. However, I can only get these to play if I hardcode the filetype extension.
The problem with that is that if I designate ".mov" then my .wav files will not play, or vice versa.
[This is my code ][2]

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: please share your code as text instead of this image so people could copy and debug it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `path` contains a name already, you can pass `nil` for type:

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: path, ofType: nil)
```

Just make sure that your `itemArray` contains not only file names, but also file extensions, like this:

```
itemArray = [
    "file1.mov",
    "file2.wav",
    ...
]
```